# Making a Stand-Alone EXE File

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm currently using Visual Studio 2010 to make a Visual Basic project. I'm trying to make a standard .EXE file for distribution but everytime I go to publish, I keep seeing it make a Click Once application.

Is there a way to complete and build a project in VStudio 2010 without making it as a Click-Once application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't `Publish` it; that is what is making it a clickonce application. Just `Build Solution`; this will create the exe in the specified output directory (usually debug or release depending on your current Configuration.